# Using statistics to find probability that event A happened but not B, and the reverse

Tags: probability, statistics

I was thinking about stories that sometimes pop up on the news about friends that have a bet involving the last one of them living.  For a side project, I wrote some code that brute forces samples and comes up with the individual probabilities of a person being alive on day x.

so maybe the results look like this:

Date ......................Alice.................. Bob

6/15/2020..............    98% .......................  99%

6/15/2021.............     97% ......................   98%

etc.

I ran a bunch of random simulations using a 2016 actuarial table that I found and have a lot of data, but realized I don't know quite what to do with it.  The problem that I have is that since Alice is older, she always has a greater chance (in this model) of dying first.  There is a possibility of Bob dying first but  I'm not grasping how to model that.  I know that there is a formula to figure this out, but haven't been able to find it (or maybe I just didn't understand it when I saw it).

How would I determine the odds on a given date in the future (knowing the individual odds of an event happening on any given day) of one event happening but not the other?  And how would I expand that to 3 or more people instead of just the 2?  In the example above, how would I determine the odds of Bob being alive on 6/15/2020 but not Alice?

Comment: Well, since these are (presumably) independent distributions, just model everyone separately.  That is, Bob's life expectancy, from a given moment, will have something like a normal distribution with a mean and standard deviation.  Alice will have a different mean and a different $\sigma$.  From there it should be easy to compute the probability that Alice dies first (or conversely).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the two events ('Alice is alive at year X' and 'Bob is alive at year X') are independent I would model it with two independent binomial distributions.

Let $p$ that the probability of dying within a year. Thus, for a given age $y$ the probability of being alive (that is, of not having died in the current or in previous years) will be $(1-p)^{y}$. As Bob and Alice have different ages the probabilities of being alive are identical with respect to their age's but shifted with respect to the calendar year.

However, there are two issues as this is a simplistic analytical solution of a complex problem:

First, if you are interested in the actual modelling you will have to keep into account that once Bob or Alice (or whoever) dies, it's out of the model.

Second, the probability of dying changes with age. For instance, in Western societies the dead rate at childbirth and young ages is relatively small, steady at young ages and very high at ages close to 80 and beyond. If you are interested in the maths behind modelling age of death you may consider Leslie matrices:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leslie_matrix

which are at the heart of the analysis of age-structured populations.

Hope that helps.